# I can't edit config.inc.php file in xampp

Tags: mysql, phpmyadmin, xampp

I've tried to install nano and I did and I did a nano code(I can't remember what (it was 2 months ago)), which then made me ask for my password but I could not type so I terminated the terminal but then when I tried chmod, sudo or other code it told me it that file "config.inc.php does not exist".

Oh yeah the code was "sudo nano config.inc.php". please help I don't want a useless phpmyadmin. I also am trying to use mySQL(just for your information) and am using a Mac os Catalina 10.15.1

Please help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`sudo nano config.inc.php` will ask for a password but won't give any local echo (as you type - on *nix shells anyways). Could that have lead to your problem? Sorry, I just wanted to add a comment but Stackoverflow wouldn't let me before I have 50 reputation points.

Comment: yeah when it asked for the password: it did not let me type (but I know why now), so I terminated it but when run the command it says could not find file "config.inc.php"

Comment: I typed the password after config.inc.php but now what do I do